# How to filter a specific html tag with Apache Tika

Tags: html, xpath, html-parsing, apache-tika

I'm using **Apache Tika** to parse several webpages around the internet. I'm aiming to filter all the content in between `<article>` tags.

I have the following code setup so far:

```
        XPathParser xhtmlParser = new XPathParser("xhtml", XHTMLContentHandler.XHTML);
        Matcher contentMatcher = xhtmlParser.parse("//xhtml:article");
        ContentHandler handler = new MatchingContentHandler(
                new ToXMLContentHandler(), contentMatcher);
        ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();            
        Parser parser = new HtmlParser();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();

        try (InputStream stream = url.openStream()) {
            System.out.println("Start parsing...");
            parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, parseContext);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TikaException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(handler.toString());
```

First of all, I'm not sure if the XPath expression `"//xhtml:article"` is correct, as I'm getting no output at all printed in the console.

Second, I read on [the example pages of Tika](http://tika.apache.org/1.13/examples.html) :

> It possible to execute XPath queries on the parse results, to fetch
>   only certain bits of the XHTML.

So I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible this way. But if not, what would be the right apprach to filter this content?

I hope someone can help me with this problem,

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

As I continued trying to get things working, I think I figured something out. Tika uses the parser to read the document and parse it to a XHTML sequence. Thing is, this sequence doesn't seem to output `<article>` tags but just ignores them. Next the Xpath query on `"//article"` is issued on this generated XHTML and therefore can't find any `<article>`tag in the document.

Is this correct? Or am I totally wrong?
If this is the correct interpretation, what would be another way to achieve the intendend goal?

Comment: My guess: namespaces. How exactly does your input document look like? Did you try `//article`?

Comment: Mostly random newspages from around the internet. (Yes they do contain the `<article>` tag.

Comment: You seem to be on the right track, Tika drops the `article` element when converting the input HTML into XHTML. I think you need to look into `HtmlMapper` to define a custom mapping of the `article` element into something you can then recognize on the XHTML side.